# Replace strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, replace

This might be a very basic question. I need to write a code which works similar as string replace algorithm.

```
static string stringReplace(string s, string stringOld, string stringNew)
    {
        string newWord = "";
        int oldMax = stringOld.Length;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (index != oldMax && s[i] == stringOld[index])
            {
                if (stringOld[index] < stringNew[index])
                {
                    newWord = newWord + stringNew[index];
                    index++;
                }
                else
                {
                    newWord = newWord + stringNew[index];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                newWord = newWord + s[i];
            }
        }
        return newWord;
    }
```

Since it's 3am the code above is probably bugged. When the new word is shorter than the old one, it goes wrong. Same as when it's longer. When the index variable is equal for both stringOld and stringNew, it will do the swap. I think... Please don't post "use string.Replace(), I have to write that algorithm myself...

Comment: Define "goes wrong".  Does it crash? Produce the wrong output? Can you show an example of the wrong output?

Comment: Are you getting `ArrayOutOfBoundsExceptions`? You're accessing the `[index]` of your two strings at the same time, if one of the strings is shorter than the other than you will try to access an undefined array entry.

Comment: If the new string is longer than the old string, nothing happens, I get back the original string.
If the new string is shorter than the old string, I get: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Jeroen: I do, but I admit, I had no idea what I did type there at that time... I'm very tired and got lost so long ago.
If the old string's length is equal to the new string's length, it works.

Comment: My technical suggestion is: GO TO BED! GET SOME SLEEP!

Comment: Go get some rest, you won't write meaningful code tonight anymore. Revisit the problem tomorrow and rethink the concept (you might want to drop the index accesses on strings and instead split it in a char array).

Comment: Haha, wish I could, but exam is tomorrow.

Comment: Then you really need to get some sleep.

Comment: All right guys, thanks for your tips though. I think I would be able to solve this alone, if it wasn't that late already... Thank you againn.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to do with your code, but the problem is not a small one.
Think logically about what you are trying to do.
It is a two step process:

1. Find the starting index of stringOld in s.
2. If found replace stringOld with stringNew.

Step 1:
There are many rather complex (and elegant) efficient string search algorithms, you can search for them online or look at popular 'Introduction to Algorithms' by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest & Stein, but the naive approach involves two loops and is pretty simple. It is also described in that book (and online.)

Step 2:
If a match is found at index `i`; simply copy characters `0` to `i-1` of `s` to `newWord`, followed by `newString` and then the rest of the characters in `s` starting at index `i + oldString.Length`.